# Drove my Chevy to the levee but the levee was dry -- what levee exactly is he talking about?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

From the song [American Pie](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tc7k3krcpmbobgxvt2m5mmlzcaq?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics) by [Don McLean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_McLean):

> Bye, bye Miss American Pie
>   Drove my Chevy to the **levee** but the **levee** was dry
>   And them good ole boys were drinking whiskey and rye
>   Singin' this'll be the day that I die
>   This'll be the day that I die

What levee exactly is he talking about? The dictionary lists a couple of definitions for the word levee, but I don't know which one is used in this song.

Comment: This is as good as any explanation: http://understandingamericanpie.com/chorus.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figuratively, it means some place people go to hang out, like a quarry, lookout point, etc.

Literally, it's a river embankment.

Like so (but while sitting in a car)...:

[image: People sitting on a levee, Mississippi River, Audubon Zoo, New Orleans.jpg]

...and not so:

[image]

Comment: Meanwhile, I know that this is not a complete answer, but I just had to post it because of that second photo :D.

Comment: If you're looking for true, in-depth analysis, there is some here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275147/drove-my-chevy-to-the-levy-and-the-levy-was-dry and here: https://www.google.com.tw/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-ab&q=american+pie+lyrics+meaning&oq=american+pie+lyrics+meaning&gs_l=serp.3..0l6j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1.2290.2531.0.2770.2.2.0.0.0.0.90.173.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.171.NP2GWP-R_ro